# Simple Recursive Query child to last parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, recursive-query

I need to retrieve the last (or first) id of a child's parent.

Example:

```
ID     PARENT_ID
----------------
1      NULL
2      1 
3      2
```

So if I search the parent id of id=3 I would have 1 as result.

I tried this but it gives me the same id...

```
with 
   tree(id)
as
(
   select id
   from myTable
   where id = 3
   union all
   select t.id 
   from myTable t
   inner join tree on tree.id = t.father_id
)
select *
from tree;
```

I already saw examples here and on several websites ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some inconsistent naming here. But anyway, your CTE needs to include the `parent_id` too.

Like this:

```
with 
   tree(id,parent_id)
as
(
   select id, parent_id
   from myTable
   where id = 3
   union all
   select t.id, t.parent_id
   from myTable t
   inner join tree on t.id = tree.parent_id
)
select *
from tree;
```

Comment: Ok thank you, it works!
Just changed the 'tree' param and the second select param o t.father_id